# How to run .sh script with php?

Tags: php, bash, apache2, raspbian, shell-exec

I am using raspberry pi 3(raspbian jessie) to capture image using fswebcam remotely using shell script and php. Since "motion" is running i need to stop the service then capture image and then restart it.

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M")
sudo service motion stop
fswebcam -r 640x480 --no-banner /var/www/html/sm/webcam/$DATE.jpg
sudo service motion start
```

The script works fine in terminal.Script is saved in var/www/html/sm.  chmod +x webcam.sh also checked.

I also wrote a php script to execute above script using apache2 server.

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('/var/www/html/sm/webcam.sh');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

I was looking for a solution for past 6 hours. No luck. Tried to add www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: /var/www/html/sm/camera.php, www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: /var/www/html/sm/webcam.sh in /etc/sudoers. Changed permissions for folders www,html,sm. changed sudo with visudo. nothing worked. Php files does nothing, Please help me.

Comment: check the `sm/` directory permissions .

Comment: Check the apache2 logs, what do they say ?

Comment: I checked apache error log i found the error
    'We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
    Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:
     #1) Respect the privacy of others.
     #2) Think before you type.
     #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

     sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified'

Comment: Also tried to execute the file using the user www-data(sudo -u www-data ./wecam.sh) it gives same error. and asking for passowrd

Comment: Instead of shell_exec why try using exec('sudo bash /var/www/html/sm/webcam,sh')

Comment: Tried exe() Still it doesn't work.