# Executing bash script from PHP on raspbian

Tags: php, bash, apache, shell, raspbian

I have a script that calls fswebcam to capture a jpg with my USB camera. I've made it executable with "chmod +x webcam.sh" :

File : /var/www/html/webcam.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=$(date + "%Y-%m-%d_%H%M")
fswebcam -r 640x480 /home/pi/webcam/$DATE.jpg
```

This is working fine in command line without sudo, so I've made a small PHP page :

File : /var/www/html/index.php

```
<?php
 $output = shell_exec('sh /var/www/html/webcam.sh');
 echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

When I go to the webpage, I just get a blank page and no jpg is created in my webcam folder.

I got the following error :
[Apache2 error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjepA.png)

So I've tried modifying my call in PHP, to :

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('/usr/bin/sudo /bin/bash /var/www/html/webcam.sh');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

I've also add the following to sudoers file

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /path/to/script
```

But I still get the error : [apache2 log error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIoYt.png)

I've tried everything from this thread : [How to run .sh script with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42473246/how-to-run-sh-script-with-php)

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks in advance,

Victor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off:

- **Don't use sudo if you don't have a *very* good reason for it.**
- `sh` does not necessarily invoke `bash`.
- `sudo` expects a password, but you didn't provide any hence the error.

I suggest trying with `exec` instead of `shell_exec` (there is a difference between the two):

```
<?php
    exec('/var/www/html/webcam.sh', $output, $exitCode);

    echo 'Exit code: '.$exitCode.' <hr />';
    echo implode('<br />', $output);
```

Another source of your problem could be permission related:

The webserver usually runs as a different user.

Make sure the webserver can actually write to the output directory.

Comment: If it still does not work, please post the output of the script.

Comment: I've tried the above code, but I got an error from the server : HTTP error 500. In the error log I can see : "PHP parse error : syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in /var/www/html/index.php on line 3". 
If I comment those echo lines, I get a blank page, and the error log gives : "Error opening device : /dev/video0
open : Permission denied "

Comment: Ok it is working now ! I've checked the last thing you told me about permission. So I gave permission to the server to access the camera with : "adduser www-data video" and then gave it permission to write the folder with : " chown -R www-data /home/pi/webcam".

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please consider upvoting and accepting it. Thank you :)